# Count the number of unique strings in a list? Python 3

Tags: python, list, count, duplicates, unique

I am new to Python. I have a list, with duplicate entries. Is their any way you can count the number of UNIQUE strings? Regards,

```
input1 = input("Name ")
input2 = []
input2.append(input1)
while input1:
  input1 = input("Name ")
  input2.append(input1)
```

I just want to print out the number of unique names entered. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to delete line 3 and reverse lines 5 and 6. This will avoid capturing the empty string that ends the while loop.

Comment: Thank you @StevenRumbalski that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
len(set(input2))

len(set(n[5:] for n in input2))
```

Comment: I've tried using that, but it didn't work. 

    `Name: Nick
    Name: Sam
    Name: Nick
    Name: Rob
    Name #whitespace
    4 #len(set(input2))
['Nick', 'Sam', 'Nick', 'Rob', '']`

Comment: It gives a length of four because it counts the empty string at the end of your list as a unique element.  Apply the changes suggested in my comments to your question and the problem will go away.

Comment: What is `len(set(n[5:] for n in input2))` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

We can use Counter from collections

```
>>> a=['Jack','Jill','Jack']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> myDict=Counter(a);
>>> myDict


Counter({'Jack': 2, 'Jill': 1})
```

Then we can use myDict as a dictionary only